# Exeption of type 'System.exepction' Was thrown

Tags: specflow

I have install Specflow extantion in my Visual studio 2022

I am trying to open new Specflow project in Visual studio 2022

I getr this message: Exeption of type 'System.exepction' Was thrown

I have updated and reinstall the Specflow

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a tough question to answer, and a tough one to ask. We need more information, and I wonder if the Visual Studio log would help: [Troubleshooting Extensions with the Activity Log](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/troubleshooting-extensions-with-the-activity-log/). Can you give us some more debugging info from the VS log?